# Where to store a value that changes rarely?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a website in ASP.NET C# and I need to store a value that changes rarely. Example : Tax. The tax changes once a year or so. I would like to store it somewhere that a user could edit it without recompiling the website. What's the best approach for this? Also I can't use a database.
Here's what I thought :

1. Store it in a xml file
2. Store it in a text file
3. Store it in Web.Config

Comment: It's an `AppSetting`. Store it in the `web.config`.

Comment: Even if I need to store the tax of 20 countries?

Comment: Store it anywhere you want to , just remember that if you store it in `web.config` , then on any modification to `web.config`, your application pool will be recycled.

Comment: I think any one of those 3 options would work just fine.

Comment: If you need to store multiple rates, either store it in a database table, or add an [ISO alpha-2 country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements) as a prefix to each and stash it in the web.config. My guess is that if you have multiple countries, then the user needs to select that country from a table, and you already have a column that you can add a new decimal tax rate field to. If you aren't okay with the web application restarting every time the web.config is modified, that's even more of reason to keep it in a table.

Comment: The thing is, I am not allowed to touch to the database for this project.

Comment: Is this a school project? In the "real world" (tm), your country/state/province list is stored in a table. Period. That's where tax rate lives, in the same row, since it's directly married to country. Your UI element (dropdown or whatever) is dynamically populated from this table.

Comment: No I work for the government and this is for a real project. It's not taxes that I need to store, but it's values that change as often. I can not edit the database because I don't have rights for it.

Comment: Does the database have tax rates already? You may not need to edit it; someone may be maintaining the data for you already...

Comment: No there isn't. The data needs to be editable from someone who doesn't use a database.

Comment: Take a look at my comment above about prepending the ISO country code as part of the key for the AppSetting.  Example `<key="US_TaxRate" value="5.0"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be an XML file.  XML is better than text since XML serialization is included in C# (unless you have the time to do the serialization yourself).  Alternatively if you like JSON may work also.

I don't like AppSettings becuase I prefer to use AppSettings for things specific to an instance of the application, while the tax Rate is something is more global than the AppInstance itself.  (like server addresses and service endpoints).

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go with web.config, because it is easily accessible. Also the values read from the web.config file are cached, so reading from file (which can be expensive) only happens once. When you change the value all you need to do is refresh the website in iis and restart the application pool.

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <key="Tax" value="5.8"/>
</appSettings>
```

To access in the code:

```
decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tax"]);
```

Comment: Only one issue with that, any changes to web.config will cause the application pool to recycle, not really sure if that is going to be issue with the OP,

Comment: Not a problem, I was just wondering if the web.config was appropriate to store values that are subject to change, because I need to store around 15 of them.

Comment: @loli, it's not easily unit-tested, but it is easy to work with.

Comment: @ps2goat really? I never had a problem unit testing keys from the web.config. I think you are talking about Application variables `HttpContext.Current.Application["Tax"]`. Because application variables are pretty annoying to unit test.